# "That's just part of it" vs "that's just a part of it"

Tags: expressions, idioms

Which version is more correct/common?

Example:

> Speaker A: Why did you leave the party? Because some guys made fun of
>   you?
>
> Speaker B: Just (a) part of it.
>
> Speaker A: What's the other?

Answer (score 4):

1. They are both correct grammatically, and they mean essentially the same thing.
2. To me, there is a slight difference in connotation:

   - *part of it* -- emphasizes/suggests an integral connection between the part and the whole; doesn't lose sight of the whole, while pointing out that something is missing without this part
   - *a part of it* -- emphasizes that there could be multiple parts, and the division into parts could be more or less arbitrary; emphasizes the part(s), perhaps losing sight of the whole somewhat; de-emphasizes any organic connection between the part(s) and the whole

   This difference in connotation is not necessarily what is meant in each case, or even in general.  It is a possible difference, and thus a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more common for Speaker B to reply:

> That's part of it.

However, I think that either one is grammatically acceptable. (I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it's a regional difference, but can't prove that.)

In case you were interested, both phrases (just a part of it, just part of it) are increasing in frequency, although the shorter phrase is currently winning out. Check out the ngram [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just%20part%20of%20it%2Cjust%20a%20part%20of%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20part%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20a%20part%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0).